# Android Studio Threads Handler

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Im trying to make a program that when i press a button it will show the speed of my arduino car and the distance travelled. Im trying to constantly update the distance in TextView.

Here is my initialization of Handler in the onCreate() that should set my TextView text to distance:

```
mHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
            String stringss = bundle.getString("myKey");
            tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zval);
            tv2.setText("Distance is :  " + stringss);
        }
    };
```

And here is my thread that does the work in the background

```
btnDist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    int distance = distanta(); //function that returns distance/secound
                    int dist = 0;
                    while(distance > 0) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        }

                        dist += distance;
                    }
                        String dateString = String.valueOf(dist);
                        msg(dateString);
                        bundle.putString("myKey", dateString);
                        msg.setData(bundle);
                        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

                }
            };
            Thread mythread = new Thread(runnable);
            mythread.start();
        }
    });
```

The application runs and doesn't crash but my textview doesn't get updated at all.
   I'm new to java threads so i might have done something wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to find the time of the arduino traveled:

```
TextView TimerBox;
long startTime = 0;

Handler timerHandler = new Handler();

//this updates the textbox
Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        int seconds =  (int) (millis / 1000);
        int decis = (int) ((millis % 1000)/10);

        TimerBox.setText(String.format("Time: %d.%02d", seconds, decis));
        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 10);
    }
};
```

This initializes a new Handler with a specific function that will update the timer textview.

When you want it to run, code this:

```
startTime =  System.currentTimeMillis();

timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
```

and when you want it to stop, use this:

```
timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
```

this solution will require you to calculate the distance traveled yourself based on velocity and acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesnt work is because `Handler` runs the message handler on the thread on which it is created by default. In your example this is the thread `mythread`. This means you're trying to update the UI from a different thread than the UI thread which doesnt usually work.

It can be fixed by specifying the `Looper` on which the Handler should run, like `mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {`

Comment: It dosn't work , the distance variable should add the current distance and the value should keep on incrementing as long as the car keeps on moving. I made a timer and multyply the speed of the car with the time to get the distance. Thank you for ur answer and for ur time!

Answer (score 0):

im sorry, this is a misunderstanding. that is not my code, my only code is only this

```
    if(seconds == 2){
seconds = 0;
decis = 0;
}
```

i just cant comment on Chi-Young Jeffrey Lii's answer because my rep is not enough, i just want to know how to read the seconds variable

Comment: his does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).